# Cakephp retrieving file data upload

Tags: php, image, cakephp, upload

on my form i have a upload input

```
echo $this->Form->input('imagem', array('type'=>'file'));
```

and when it tries to cheack size, type and load all the array data inside "imagem" input it just simply can't.

```
function uploadImagem() {
    $file = $this->data['Produto']['imagem'];
    print_r($file);
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $id = String::uuid();
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], APP.'uploads'.DS.$id)) {
          $this->data['Upload']['id'] = $id;
          $this->data['Upload']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
          $this->data['Upload']['filename'] = $file['name'];
          $this->data['Upload']['filesize'] = $file['size'];
          $this->data['Upload']['filemime'] = $file['type'];
          return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i print the $file it should display "Array()" but it's retrieving me the name of the file.
And if i try use/print `$this->data['Produto']['imagem']['name']` or `$this->data['Produto']['imagem']['error']`, it just give me an error

Illegal string offset 'name'

Could someone tell how can i upload correctly with Cakephp!?

Comment: have you used `'type' => 'file'` in `Form->create`

Answer (score 3):

The fact that your `$_FILE` is only a filename and not an array indicate that your form does not have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
With Cake you can achieve this with the `FormHelper` (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-create):

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Mymodel', array('type' => 'file')) ?>
```

Also to manage file upload in CakePHP, I recommend you to use this great plugin: https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But still doesn't work! Could you give me a link how can install or use this plugin?

Comment: The documentation is available here: http://cakephp-upload.readthedocs.org/en/latest/